# Bootstrap Modal Resize on Content Change

Tags: javascript, resize, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, onchange

I have a bootstrap modal window which contains a form. If the user submits the form, it gets validated via Ajax. If there is any error it is shown above the form in the modal (without reloading the page).

Thus, i need a way to resize the modal when the content changes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

have you tried not to set the height of the div?

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem. I just remove the max-height.

```
.modal-body {
  overflow-y: auto;
  /*max-height: 400px;*/
  padding: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the latter answer suggests to edit a core css definition, I would discourage this, it is bad practice. In **whatever.css** you can use CSS Point Score to overwrite it like so:

```
div.modal-body {
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: none;
    padding: 15px;
}
```